# GCP - Cloud Run / Anthos / Versioning / rollout/ production /

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, rollout

You are managing **an application** deployed on **Cloud Run** for **Anthos**, and you need to define a **strategy** for **deploying new versions** of the **application**. You want to evaluate the new code with a **subset of production traffic** to decide whether to proceed with the **rollout**. What should you do?

A. Deploy a new revision to Cloud Run with the new version. Configure traffic percentage between revisions.

B. Deploy a new service to Cloud Run with the new version. Add a Cloud Load Balancing instance in front of both services.

**C. In the Google Cloud Console page for Cloud Run, set up continuous deployment using Cloud Build for the development branch. As part of the Cloud Build trigger, configure the substitution variable TRAFFIC_PERCENTAGE with the percentage of traffic you want directed to a new version.**

D. In the Google Cloud Console, configure Traffic Director with a new Service that points to the new version of the application on Cloud Run. Configure Traffic Director to send a small percentage of traffic to the new version of the application.

I feel that **answer is 'C'** but many chose 'A' too... Which is correct? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the TRAFFIC_POURCENTAGE substitution variable on Cloud Run continuous deployment page.

Comment: Thank you. So would 'A' be the best answer?

Comment: Yes, A is the correct answer. C could be if the feature existed!

Comment: This look like an exam question. Are these allowed here ?

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/rollouts-rollbacks-traffic-migration

A:Deploy a new revision to Cloud Run with the new version. Configure traffic percentage between revisions